# Calculation of minimum distance between coordinate points

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I am having a problem in building up VBcode for getting the minimum distance between a set of coordinate points. What I am actually trying is to find the minimum distance between one set of coordinate points `(A(x1,y1),Bx2,y2),C(x3,y3),D(x4,y4),E(x5,y5))` with respect to another set of coord points `(i(x1,y1),j(x2,y2),k(x3,y3),l(x4,y4),m(x5,y5))`.
I hope you understand what I am trying to interpret.

Can anybody help me out?

---

```
Public Function DoSearch(ByVal SearchCritera As Bracket, ByVal ListToSearchFrom As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of TRacksDefinitions.Racks.Bracket)) As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of TRacksDefinitions.Search.SearchBracket) Implements TRacksDefinitions.Search.ISearch.DoSearch


        _results.Clear()
        For Each b As Bracket In ListToSearchFrom
            'LAST POINT DISTANCE., WT DIST, number of points, similarity of points (-1 if not used),
            Dim dist() As Double = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
            Dim dx As Double = b.RearPoints(b.RearPoints.Length - 2).X - SearchCritera.RearPoints(SearchCritera.RearPoints.Length - 2).X
            Dim dy As Double = b.RearPoints(b.RearPoints.Length - 2).Y - SearchCritera.RearPoints(SearchCritera.RearPoints.Length - 2).Y
            Dim dz As Double = b.RearPoints(b.RearPoints.Length - 2).Z - SearchCritera.RearPoints(SearchCritera.RearPoints.Length - 2).Z

            dist(0) += Math.Sqrt(dx ^ 2 + dy ^ 2 + dz ^ 2)
            dist(1) += Math.Abs(SearchCritera.Wallthickness - b.Wallthickness)
            dist(2) += Math.Abs(SearchCritera.RearPoints.Count - b.RearPoints.Count)
            If SearchCritera.RearPoints.Count = b.RearPoints.Count Then
                Dim d1, d2 As Decimal

                ' Dim sum As Double = 0
                For i As Integer = 0 To b.RearPoints.Count - 1
                    d1 = Math.Abs(SearchCritera.RearPoints(i).X - b.RearPoints(i).X)
                    d2 = Math.Abs(SearchCritera.RearPoints(i).Y - b.RearPoints(i).Y)

                  ?????????????????

                Next
            Else
                dist(3) = -1
            End If
```

@LarsTech 
The above is code which I have created until now and the next step is calculating the min distance criteria.

Search criteria: rear points is the one we get from solidworks and b.rearpoints is the one present in database we compare both of them find the one which is very similar to the one in database.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which distances are you considering? A->i, B->j, C->k or A->i..m, B->i..m, etc.?

Comment: is it vb.net or vbscript? the two languages have little in common anymore.

Comment: ya u r correct i am trying to match A,B,C,D,E with i,j,k,l,m i.e A>i,B>j ...but the points get loaded from database .......its vb.net

Answer (score 1):

You need a distance formula:

```
Public Function GetDistance(ByVal startPoint As Point, ByVal endPoint As Point) As Integer
  Return Math.Sqrt((Math.Abs(endPoint.X - startPoint.X) ^ 2) + _
                   (Math.Abs(endPoint.Y - startPoint.Y) ^ 2))
End Function
```

Then you just need to loop through all of your points to find which distance is the smallest:

```
Dim listOne As New List(Of Point)
listOne.Add(New Point(10, 10))
listOne.Add(New Point(20, 20))
listOne.Add(New Point(30, 30))
listOne.Add(New Point(40, 40))
listOne.Add(New Point(50, 50))

Dim listTwo As New List(Of Point)
listTwo.Add(New Point(50, 10))
listTwo.Add(New Point(50, 20))
listTwo.Add(New Point(50, 30))
listTwo.Add(New Point(50, 40))
'listTwo.Add(New Point(50, 50))

Dim minDistance As Nullable(Of Integer)
For Each p1 As Point In listOne
  For Each p2 As Point In listTwo
    Dim distance As Integer = GetDistance(p1, p2)
    If minDistance Is Nothing OrElse distance < minDistance Then
      minDistance = distance
    End If
  Next
Next

MessageBox.Show("Minimum Distance = " & minDistance.ToString)
```

Comment: but how can we adapt it to a condition where the coordinates is retrieved from solidworks , how can we use those coordinates ...into this logic ......:)

Comment: @user1330300 Replace `listOne` and `listTwo` with lists that you get from your database.  You can convert the sample code into a function where you pass each list as a parameter and return the `minDistance` value.

Comment: @LarsTech There is no need to take the square root since for all non-negative real a,b, if a>b then a^2>b^2.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: How do you like my answer?

Answer (score 0):

In two dimensions, depending upon the distribution of the points, if N exceeds 9, it may make sense to partition the space into int(sqrt(N)-1)^2 identically-sized "boxes".  If any box contains more than a hundred or so points, randomly pick ten or so points from the most populous box, find the smallest distance between any pair, and then repartition with a box size of either that smallest distance or a box size reduced by a factor of int(sqrt(k)-1) where k is the population of that box [if a box contains that many points, there must be two within that fraction of the box size.

In the worst case this algorithm could perform badly, since there could be a very dense concentration of points that somehow never get arbitrarily chosen for the distance test, and it could take awhile before the space gets subdivided finely enough to separate them.  In practice, however, the points would likely get chosen at some point, allowing the collection to get quickly subdivided.